# React App to invoke `aws s3 sync` to upload client local folder to s3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

I want to build a react app that can invoke `aws s3 sync`. The purpose of this react app to upload client folder fast to s3 bucket.

Basically, the client have 10G images, each is around 1MB. The client should

1. access react app via browser;
2. enter local folder path and s3 bucket destination
3. click a button, which invoke `aws s3 sync` to sync the local folder to the s3 bucket.

Is it doable or is there any other way to achieve client fast upload of local file to s3 via react app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this would not be possible because the `aws s3 sync` command needs to run on the local computer and web pages do not (normally) have the ability to execute commands on the local machine (otherwise hackers would take over everyone's computer!).

You might be able to achieve it by creating a browser plug-in that can be triggered by the web app.

Some alternatives:

- Have them execute `aws s3 sync` command themselves, or via a script you provide
- Have them use a utility like [Explorer](https://www.msp360.com/explorer.aspx) or [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/) to upload the files with a drag & drop interface
- Make a web page where they can drag & drop files onto the page, which will then upload the files (without using `aws s3 sync`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm considering using option 3. My questions are if user have 100000 files,  what `aws-sdk` s3 command should I use to achieve fast upload as `aws s3 sync` and how will user drag and & drop 100000 files?

Comment: Any Drag & Drop magic will need to work within normal browser capabilities (much like Dropbox allows you to drag and drop a file into the browser). It would _not_ be using the `aws` command, which is something that needs to be installed on the local computer. For a large number of files (even 50+), I would not recommend doing it via a browser. You would really want something (as suggested above) directly transferring to Amazon S3.

Comment: I see. What if switch react app to build a desktop app, would that have the capability to invoke cli command like `aws s3 sync`? So what user can do is download the app, and do the step 2,3 in the question.

Comment: For security reasons, a web page cannot run commands on the user's computer. The user would need an app installed on their computer to do such an upload efficiently.  10GB is a huge amount of data to upload.